# OpenUI5 Routing Like ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: model-view-controller, sapui5

I am attempting to build an OpenUI5 application that first runs through a Router for all its navigation config. **I can see that my Routes are firing, but they never attempt to load Controllers/Views**. I would expect to see 404 errors when OpenUI5 tries to find my missing Views.

I'm trying to mirror ASP.NET, which follows what I'd call a **Route-First** approach. Before a Controller is instantiated in ASP.NET, the Routing engine first needs to match a Route to a given URL; the matching Controller is then instantiated.

I have just two files, a Component.js file, and an index.html file. I will later add Controllers and Views, but with my current setup, I do not even see OpenUI5 firing off any HTTP requests to fetch my missing Controllers/Views.

### Component.js

```
Query.sap.declare("cag.sbx.Component");
sap.ui.core.UIComponent.extend("cag.sbx.Component",
{
    metadata:
    {
        name: "OpenUI5 Simple Routing",
        includes: [],
        dependencies: {
            libs: ["sap.m", "sap.ui.layout"],
            components: []
        },
        routing:
        {
            config:
            {
                viewType: "JS",
                viewPath: "cag.sbx.views",
                targetControl: "emptyElement",
                clearTarget: false
            },
            routes:
            [
                {
                    pattern: "products/{id}",
                    name: "product",
                    view: "Products"
                },
                {
                    pattern: "",
                    name: "default",
                    view: "Home"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    init: function()
    {
        sap.ui.core.UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);
        // this component should automatically initialize the router!
        this.getRouter().initialize();
    },
    createContent: function()
    {
        var panel = new sap.ui.commons.ResponsiveContainer("emptyElement");
        return panel;
    }
});
```

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
            src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
            data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
            data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.commons,sap.m"></script>
    <script>
        jQuery.sap.registerModulePath("cag.sbx", "./components/sbx");
        new sap.ui.core.ComponentContainer({
                name: 'cag.sbx'
            }).placeAt("content");
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have created a GitHub repo with the full project and a JSFiddle. In the JSFiddle, you'll notice that there's no HTTP request for a Products.View.js or Login.View.js file if using your browser dev tools.

https://github.com/peder/openui5-simplerouting/

http://jsfiddle.net/nbjvqL96/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually missing two things here :

1. The base container needs to contain either an `sap.m.App` or `SplitApp` so that the pages can be aggregated.
2. `targetAggregation`  is where these created pages will be placed in `targetControl`'s aggregation. In case of `App` its `pages` and for splitapp it can be `masterPages` or `detailPages`

I have the updated code at http://jsfiddle.net/nbjvqL96/2/